# How to open drawer from a screen? communication between screen through viewmodel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer

I would like to open a drawer from a topAppBar icon on the first screen of my navigation host.

I saw a sample code from [JetChat](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetchat)
I followed what it's implemented there but it's not working like them and I don't know why.

Here are my codes

```
@Composable
fun NavigationAuthenticated(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Routes.Messages.route) {
        composable(route = Routes.Messages.route) {
            MessagesScreen(
                navController = navController,
                messagesViewModel = viewModel(factory = MessagesViewModel.Factory),
                homeViewModel = viewModel(factory = HomeViewModel.Factory)
            )
        }
        composable(
            route = Routes.Conversation.route + "/{phoneNumber}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("phoneNumber") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = ""
                }
            )
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            ConversationScreen(
                navController,
                conversationViewModel = viewModel(factory = ConversationViewModel.Factory)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main activity

```
class HomeActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    companion object {
        fun startActivity(context: Context) {
            context.startActivity(
                Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java)
            )
        }
    }

    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalBackPressedDispatcher provides this@HomeActivity.onBackPressedDispatcher
            ) {
                HomeBaseView(viewModel) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavigationAuthenticated(navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeBaseView(
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    WizardOfOzTheme {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            val context = LocalContext.current

            val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            val drawerOpen by homeViewModel.drawerShouldBeOpened.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
            if (drawerOpen) {
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    try {
                        drawerState.open()
                    } finally {
                        homeViewModel.resetOpenDrawerAction()
                    }
                }
            }
            if (drawerState.isOpen) {
                BackPressHandler {
                    scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                }
            }

            val items = listOf(
                Icons.Default.Message,
                Icons.Default.Favorite,
                Icons.Default.Face,
                Icons.Default.Email
            )
            val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(items[0]) }

            ModalNavigationDrawer(
                drawerState = drawerState,
                drawerContent = {
                    ModalDrawerSheet {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
                        items.forEach { item ->
                            NavigationDrawerItem(
                                icon = { Icon(item, contentDescription = null) },
                                label = {
                                    Text(item.name)
                                },
                                selected = item == selectedItem.value,
                                onClick = {
                                    scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                                    selectedItem.value = item
                                },
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                            )
                        }
                        NavigationDrawerItem(
                            icon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Logout, contentDescription = null) },
                            label = { Text("Sign Out") },
                            selected = false,
                            onClick = { Toast.makeText(context, "Sign out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) },
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                        )
                    }
                }
            ) {
                content()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **MessagesScreen** code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MessagesScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    messagesViewModel: MessagesViewModel,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier,
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Messages",
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { homeViewModel.openDrawer(); Log.d("MessagesScreen", "Clicked on Menu") }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, "ContentDescription")
                    }
                },
            )
        },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            MessagesScreenContent(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .wrapContentSize(),
                navController = navController,
                messagesViewModel = messagesViewModel,
                openDrawer = { homeViewModel.openDrawer() }
            )
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun MessagesScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavController,
    messagesViewModel: MessagesViewModel = viewModel(),
    openDrawer: () -> Unit
) {
    Log.i("MessagesScreen", "MsgScreen : ${messagesViewModel.allMessages.value?.size}")
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { openDrawer() }) {
                Text("Click to open")
            }
            MessagesList(
                messagesLiveData = messagesViewModel.allMessagesAboutUser,
                onMessageItemClicked = { user ->
                    navController.navigate("conversations/$user")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the `HomeViewModel` that is used as an intermediary between the **HomeScreenContent** and the **MessagesScreenContent**

```
class HomeViewModel: ViewModel() {
    companion object {
        private val TAG = HomeViewModel::class.java.name
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                // val savedStateHandle = createSavedStateHandle()
                HomeViewModel()
            }
        }
    }

    private val _drawerShouldBeOpened = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val drawerShouldBeOpened = _drawerShouldBeOpened.asStateFlow()

    fun openDrawer() {
        _drawerShouldBeOpened.value = true
        Log.d(TAG, "openDrawer()")
    }

    fun resetOpenDrawerAction() {
        _drawerShouldBeOpened.value = false
        Log.d(TAG, "resetOpenDrawerAction()")
    }
}
```

When I click on the Hamburger icon from MessagesScreen, the log print the correct information

```
2023-06-29 11:01:29.222  1772-1772  com.stocki...eViewModel yyyyyyyy      D  openDrawer()
2023-06-29 11:01:29.226  1772-1772  MessagesScreen          yyyyyyyy      D  Clicked on Menu
```

But there is no change in the HomeBaseView, in the drawer, the drawer is not opening.
I don't know if it's either because it's not receiving the information about the change of the drawer state or because there is another problem.

I am surprised because I think that I correctly copied the code from the android sample and except that I am not using Fragment, everything looks identical

Where is the issue coming from, please?

Comment: Could you check that you're not creating multiple instances of the same viewModel?

Comment: How can I check it, please @m.reiter?

Comment: And, @m.reiter, how to ensure that I am using the same instance everywhere?

Comment: Checking is easy: just add logs to the inits of your viewmodels. If one logs unexpectedly twice, you know you f*cked up :D